# Generic method to use a superclass of the generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have a generic class:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T> { 
  ...
}
```

Now inside this class, I want to have a method that allows me to interact with another generic, which could be of generic type `T` or any superclass of `T`, for example:

```
public void DoSomething<T1>(List<T1> things) 
  where T : T1 // of course this won't compile
{
  ...
}
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, I'm afraid. The closest you could come would be to have a method in a *non-generic* class - possibly an extension method:

```
public static MyGenericClassExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomething<T, T1>(this MyGenericClass<T> @this,
                                          List<T1> things)
        where T : T1
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That's fine, because it's introducing both type parameters at the same time.

Of course, an alternative would be to keep the method as an instance method within `MyGenericClass<T>`, without the constraint, and check the constraint at execution time. That would be unfortunate in terms of the compile-time safety and general declarative nature of generics, but it *may* end up working out better for you.

Comment: Interesting because the constraint `where T1 : T` is allowed. Any idea why the OPs constraint isn't allowed?

Comment: @mikez: Yes - the OP's constraint is on `T`, which isn't a type parameter of that method. In my method, both type constraints are introduced at the same time, so you can constrain one based on the other.

Comment: +1 Hey Jon, thanks for the answer.  Just thought you'd like a ping to see the alternative answer I came up with.

Comment: Based on the fact that you gave the correct answer to the question I asked, even though I solved it differently, I'll give you answer credit.

Answer (score 0):

@JonSkeet's answer, as always, is on the mark, but I did find another way to do this without causing any upheaval in my code.  I created another generic class and modified the existing class, as follows:

```
public class MyGenericClass<T, TBase> 
  where T : TBase
{ 
  public void DoSomething(List<TBase> things) 
  {
    ...
  }
}

public class MyGenericClass<T> : MyGenericClass<T, T>
{
  ...
}
```

This way I get the desired functionality while still maintaining backward compatibility, i.e. all existing code that is using the original single-type generic will still work.

Comment: That's assuming you only want to be able to call it with a single `TBase` type for any given instance of `MyGenericClass`. It wasn't clear that that restriction would be acceptable.

Comment: @JonSkeet - true, fair point.  Your answer still wins if you want to allow any base class.